# https with Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager

Tags: local, azure-service-fabric

I develop Service Fabric applications, and I have the Service Fabric SDK installed locally, which provides the useful, if sparse, Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager (servicefabriclocalclustermanager.exe). By default this only seems to support http. There is no obvious way to create a https cluster from the UI. I have done some research, and I have managed to create myself a https cluster, but in order to do that I had to modify a ClusterConfig.json file manually and run the CreateServiceFabricCluster.ps1 powershell script. This doesn't integrate with the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager, and if I want to manipulate it, I basically have to use powershell commands. This is manageable, but it would be much easier to just use the system tray widget if possible.

Is there a way to use the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager with a local cluster configured for https? I know there are a whole load of scripts in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup, which seem to be what the Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager uses to configure the cluster it interacts with, and there are Secure versions of those scripts, but I can't see how to make use of them.

Comment: My first take on this would be to ask why you need to. The local cluster manager is intended for local development purposes. The cluster manager running on Azure is configured to utilize HTTPS by default (because you set up the necessary certificate as part of that configuration). What're you aiming to achieve with local HTTPS that you need to bother with the effort?

Comment: We have a big legacy app that we're currently turning into a set of service fabric microservices (slowly).  We recently started using https for that app, which was fine in prod, where our microservices are also https. However our dev environments are now an awkward mix of https app and http microservices. Some microservices have UI that we embed in the main app with an iframe. That no longer works because the iframe content is insecure while the host is secure. I can't change the big app, just my SF cluster.

Comment: I guess I'm still not understanding the dependency on the cluster manager as it's just launching the SF explorer used to monitor the cluster. HTTPS should really only be a concern for the individual services and that's just a matter of ensuring you've got an available endpoint + service setup for each one. How you elect to monitor it (with SFX or other tooling) should be independent of that.

Comment: Regardless, it doesn't speak to the dev cluster itself, but you might find some useful tips in the [standalone guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-for-windows-server) as it mentions the various secure scripts you'd use to create a secure cluster on-premise. But again, note that it also mentions that this certificate protects cluster maintenance operations (e.g. through SFX or PowerShell) and you shouldn't necessarily have a dependency on that with your own app.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the standalone docs to get to where I am now, and it kind of works. I guess the real issue is that we're using the reverse proxy within service fabric, and it's that that needs to be setup with https. I can do that, it works fine, but the workflow isn't great. I'll keep plugging at it. If it was up to me I'd set the main app back to http and avoid the problem altogether, but hey ho... :)

Comment: It's not GA yet, but you might take a look at the [YARP project](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy). I got the sense from a recent community call that it may one day replace the reverse proxy as a whole. Available from preview8 and up, but won't ship with 1.0.

Comment: Interesting, I'll keep an eye on that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I have been using for quite some time.

> The key here is to create your own custom Https Certificate locator
> and use this to find the correct certificate based on your
> environment. For example, locally it makes sense to use the default
> `localhost` HTTPs certificate created by Visual Studio tooling. In
> other environments you likely need to identify the correct certificate based on
> some criteria like its *Common Name*.

Override the `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` operation in your `ASP.NET` stateless service to configure the https port. This is also where you supply the custom `HttpsCertificateLocator` implementation.

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                return new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseKestrel(opt =>
                    {
                        int port = serviceContext.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint").Port;
                        opt.Listen(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(new HttpsCertificateLocator().GetHttpsCertificateFromStore());
                        });
                    })
```

### Example Https Certificate Locator

```
public class HttpsCertificateLocator : BaseHttpsCertificateLocator, IHttpsCertificateLocator
{
    private readonly string[] _cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority;
    private readonly bool _isDevelopment;
    private const string Development = nameof(Development);

    public HttpsCertificateLocator(string environmentName = null, string[] cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority = null)
    {
        _cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority = cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority ?? CommonCertificates.Intranet.DefaultCNs;

        var environment = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(environmentName)
            ? (System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? Development)
            : environmentName;

        _isDevelopment = string.Compare(environment, Development, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If environment is Development, finds and returns the ASP .NET Core HTTPS development certificate in development environment.
    /// In other developments, returns a HTTPS certificate that is assumed installed on all Service Fabric cluster nodes
    /// </summary>
    public X509Certificate2 GetHttpsCertificateFromStore(bool httpsMandatory = true)
    {
        if (_isDevelopment)
        {
            return ReturnDevCertificate(httpsMandatory);
        }

        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;

            foreach (var subjectName in _cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority)
            {
                var matchingCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, subjectName, true);
                if (matchingCerts.Count > 0)
                {
                    return EnsureMostRecentCertificate(matchingCerts, subjectName, httpsMandatory);
                }
            }

            return EnsureMostRecentCertificate(
                new X509Certificate2Collection(), 
                _cNsToTryInOrderOfPriority.LastOrDefault() ?? "<NONE SPECIFIED>",
                httpsMandatory);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code inherits from `BaseHttpsCertificateLocator`. It provides additional functionality to locate the default development `localhost` HTTPs certificate. It also has code to find the most recent certificate (something you have to deal with when you start rolling over certificates).

```
public abstract class BaseHttpsCertificateLocator
{
    protected X509Certificate2 ReturnDevCertificate(bool httpsMandatory)
    {
        // Note: AspNet Core should auto generate/install this X509 cert on dev PCs
        const string aspNetHttpsOid = "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1";
        const string cnLocalhost = "CN=localhost";

        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByExtension, aspNetHttpsOid, true);
            var matchingCerts = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerDistinguishedName, cnLocalhost, true);
            return EnsureMostRecentCertificate(matchingCerts, cnLocalhost, httpsMandatory);
        }
    }

    protected X509Certificate2 EnsureMostRecentCertificate(
        X509Certificate2Collection marchingCerts,
        string cnName,
        bool httpsMandatory)
    {
        if (marchingCerts.Count == 0)
        {
            return httpsMandatory
                ? throw new SecurityException($"Unable to locate HTTPS X509 cert `{cnName}`")
                : default(X509Certificate2);
        }

        if (marchingCerts.Count > 1)
        {
            return marchingCerts.Cast<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(x => x.NotAfter).First();
        }

        return marchingCerts[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it enables https for a single application, is that right? If so, that's something I can do, but it doesn't solve the problem for me, unfortunately. What I'm looking for is a way to get the entire cluster using https. The Service Fabric Explorer, the Service Fabric Cluster Manager, the reverse proxy (most importantly the reverse proxy, for us) everything. In our development environments applications are accessed via the reverse proxy, mostly because it maps nicely to how we have our API management stuff set up, hence the whole cluster approach.

Comment: Correct - it's per app. If you want to provide end to end https encryption, you have to do it at individual app level; you can certainly re-use the same wildcard cert for all your apps. Beyond that, only other way is via reverse proxy - either using SF Reverse proxy or 3rd party one. Not sure unfortunately of ways to hack the local cluster manager to use https though.